# How to Retrieve Value From Firebase Database Child Node?

Tags: android, firebase, nullpointerexception, firebase-realtime-database

I need to retrieve data from the children of the child node `post_Category` in my Firebase db.

My tree structure looks like this:

[image]

I have tried this block of code in my Android Studio:

[image]

But I keep getting a null pointer exception. How can I retrieve the value from each of the children of the `post_Category` node?

Comment: In general you will have better chance of getting help if you include code/json directly in your post and also the stack trace for the crash you're getting.

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly, please dont mind. I just signed up to SO today. Thanks for pointing out..

Answer (score 1):

I suspect issue is that you need to update your code to something like following (assuming you have `Category` pojo mapped to the firebase `post_Category` data).

```
for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    Category category = childSnapshot.getValue(Category.class);
}
```

Comment: The logic is sound but I still dont know to retrieve the values inside the post_Category node.

Comment: Have you tried the code above (including creating `Category` class that maps to your json)?  If so, what error are you seeing?